# How to programatically hide a tooltip in highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to implement highcharts in a mobile application, everything works fine but there is one issue in which on changing orientation from potrait to landscape the tooltip shown for any point selected does not hide on orientation change.

Please suggest me how to hide a tooltip programatically in highcharts ..

I tried the below code:

`$('#tankActualUsagechart').highcharts().tooltip.hide();`

but this does not hide the marker which i am displaying ...

If there is a way to hide the marker i am fine with that also ..

Please help me on this issue

Comment: You find the solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/St84H/

You can hide tool tip by

```
tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have a reference to the Highcharts Chart object, you can hide the tooltip like so:

```
// create chart
var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({ /* snip */ });

// hide tooltip
myChart.tooltip.hide();
```

Comment: From question you can read: >`but this does not hide the marker which i am displaying ...`

Comment: same problem for me... did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I looked through a lot of forums and nowhere I found very easy way to show/hide a Tooltip like tooltip.enable = true/false.
The good way I came to is to set tooltip setting through Formatter in the initialization of chart.

var barsShowen - is a global variable that has a necessary state - true/false - show Tooltip or not.

This example will work in my project www.tanks-vs.com after the beginning of Dec 2014. You could see.

```
tooltip: {

    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,

    formatter: function() {

        if (barsShowen) {

            var s = '<span><b>' + this.x + '</b></span><table>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<tr><td align = "left" style = "color:' + this.series.color + ';">' + this.series.name + ': ' +'</td>' +
                    '<td><b>'+  this.y +'</b></td></tr>' ;
                });


            return s+'</table>';
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide formatter function. The trick is to return false when you do not want to show anything

Here is a little test

HTML page -

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id='toggleTooltip'>Toggle tooltip</button>
```

JS Code -

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'tooltip enabled is set to false'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
    }]
});

$('#toggleTooltip').click(function () {
    var tooltipOptions = $('#container').highcharts().tooltip.options;
    if ($(this).hasClass('enabled')) {
        tooltipOptions.formatter = null;
        $(this).removeClass('enabled');
    } else {
        tooltipOptions.formatter = function () {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).addClass('enabled');
    }
 });
});
```

See live [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arnabk/5r8pydxv/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set that marker/point default state.

Something like this:

```
chart.series[0].data[index_of_tooltip_point].setState("");
```

Comment: Can you please tell me to get the index of the tooltip ?

Comment: You can loop through all points and check which on has 'state: "hover"'. Or in formatter get hover point to some global variable and when hiding tooltip set that state.

Answer (score 1):

Try and use below code:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                   click: function(e) {
                        enabledTooltip();
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: [{
                dashStyle: "Solid"
            }, false],
             enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });



    var enabledTooltip = function(){
alert(567);
        var options = chart.options;
        options.tooltip.enabled = true;
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
};

});
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: this might give typeError like undefined as there might not be directly event exposed to programatically disable tooltip. i think anyone required to do dom manipulation done by @arnab as above.

Answer (score 1):

I use `chart.pointer.reset()` for removing marker and tooltip during `legendItemClick` and it works like a charm

[jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lbboksz/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with option `enabled` with `false` like :

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: false,        
  }
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VQcFB/)

Answer (score 0):

This is jenky but served my purposes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.highcharts-container text:last').hide()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need at run time.

chart.tooltip.hide();

It worked for me http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/tooltip-how-to-show-hide-tooltips-onblur-t5926/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update function

```
    var mychart = $('#container').highcharts();
```

For disable tooltip:

```
    mychart.update({tooltip: {enabled: false}});
```

For enable tooltip:

```
    mychart.update({tooltip: {enabled: true}});
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nz5L2pem/3/):

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `chart.myTooltip.destroy()` method to remove the tooltip manually. For example:

```
var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({ /* ... */ });
myChart.myTooltip.destroy();
```

This will remove the current instance, and it will reappear the next time you hover on a point (or whatever action the user would take to show the tooltip).