# Link table data with chart data Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, dom, highcharts

I have some data displayed in two ways.

Once as a table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Brakes</td>
      <td>34%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Headlights</td>
      <td>12%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And once as a pie chart (generated using Highchart).

Highchart places the data into SVG paths and the order of the table data and piechart paths is the same ie. Brakes is the first 'tr' anchor and the first pie chart slice.

I would like to link the two so that when I hover the table row it highlights the chart slice.

What would be the best way to do this using Jquery/javascript?

So far I have the following:

```
$(function(){
  var tr = $('table tr') // to get an array of the table rows
  var p = $('path') // to get an array of the paths


  // Sorry for my naivety but I am not too sure where to go beyond this point.

});
```

Any help that can be offered would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Considering that you might have more than one pair of table-chart,
//get the list of tables, and iterate over the charts.
var tables = $('table');
$.each(Highcharts.charts, function(chartIdx, chartElement) {

    //Get the current chart
    var chart = Highcharts.charts[chartIdx];

    //Get the current rows
    var rows = $(tables[chartIdx]).find('tr');

    //Iterate over each row
    rows.each(function(idx, element) {

        //Get the chart serie (assuming there is only one)
        var serie = chart.series[0];

        //Get the chart data corresponding to this row
        var data = serie.data[idx];

        //Attach mouseover event to it
        $(this).on('mouseover', function(event) {

            //Simulates the hover event on it, as a way to highlight it
            //Credits to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318136/1064325
            data.setState('hover');

            //Makes the tooltip for the simulated hover
            //Credits to http://stackoverflow.com/a/14650436/1064325
            chart.tooltip.refresh(data);
        });

        //Attach mouseleave event to it
        $(this).on('mouseleave', function(event) {

            //Removes the hover event simulation on it
            //Credits to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318136/1064325
            data.setState();

            //Makes the tooltip for the simulated hover
            //Credits to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20988150/1064325
            chart.tooltip.hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Make sure to execute this code after the creation of the charts.

[You can see a working fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/wxsx8dLL/11/)

Comment: this is a fantastic answer, thanks so much for your help. Out of interest what is idx?

Comment: Glad to hear it! I found your question fantastic also! But about the idx interest, I use `idx` for index, in a shorter form.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Do you know how I could amend this to be as if I am hovering over the chart segment rather than clicking on the slice? Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

Do not break your head with this, a simpler way to accomplish this is using angularjs (ng-table), you can made a complex system of table in few steps, check this links

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fjkcg)  `ng-table`

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6PFCPuFrN6lfGHjHVwGf?p=preview) `Pagination`

hope it can help you

Comment: What about the table-chart linking?